# Setup a Capistrano task to only run on deploy, not deploy:cold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, capistrano, deployment

I am using craken to run cron processes on my aws machine instance. I have defined the following custom tasks in Capistrano:

```
namespace :craken do
  desc "Install raketab"
  task :install, :roles => :cron do
    set :rails_env, "production" unless exists?(:rails_env)
    set :env_args, (exists?(:env_args) ? env_args : "app_name=#{application} deploy_path=#{current_path}")
    run "cd #{current_path} && rake #{env_args} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} craken:install"
  end
  task :uninstall, :roles => :cron do
    set :rails_env, "production" unless exists?(:rails_env)
    set :env_args, (exists?(:env_args) ? env_args : "app_name=#{application} deploy_path=#{current_path}")
    run "cd #{current_path} && rake #{env_args} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} craken:uninstall"
  end
end

before "deploy:symlink", "craken:uninstall"
after "deploy:symlink", "craken:install"
```

The problem is that the before "deploy:symlink", "craken:uninstall" causes deploy:cold to fail on first run, since the craken raketab has not yet been installed. How can I configure this to run only if it's a deploy and not a deploy:cold? Is there an environment variable that I can check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The deploy:cold task isn't recommended for use anymore.

http://www.capify.org/index.php/From_The_Beginning#About_deploy:cold

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack, change cracken:uninstall to

run "cd #{current_path} && rake #{env_args} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} craken:uninstall; true"

Or hook cracken tasks on deploy:update